Expo Submit is only submitting to TestFlight, can it create a new version for public distribution?
Everything runs successfully for 'eas submit -e production -p ios' but the build only shows up in TestFlight and now a new public version for distribution.  For Android, this config has worked for doing production releases, is there something similar for iOS?
"android": {
"track": "production"
},

The version number in your build needs to match the version number you have set up for your new release in App Store Connect.

@Paulw11 So EAS doesn't create a new release and I'll still need to do that manually before submitting?

Soo is just submitting builds to AppStore connect. You need to setup the release in App Store Connect for the build to be associated with.  Expo doesn't know what metadata or screenshots etc you want
